# pipenv install pytorch cpu + specific version

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, pipenv, pipfile

I ned to install a specific version of **pytorch** cpu mode.

With **pip** I would do it like this:

`pip install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html --trusted-host download.pytorch.org`

How can I achieve the same using Pipenv?

I tried having the following Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu"
verify_ssl = false

[packages]
torchvision = {index = "pytorch", version = "==0.4.0"}
torch = {index = "pytorch", version = "==1.2.0"}
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```sh
$ PIP_FIND_LINKS="https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html" pipenv install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu
```

But, you'll have to ensure that you add `PIP_FIND_LINKS` for any consecutive `pipenv sync`, `pipenv lock`, etc.

UPD:

You may also add `PIP_FIND_LINKS="https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html"` to the `.env` file, but it's only being loaded on `pipenv run` and `pipenv shell`.